# How to find area (in hectares) of a raster in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find the area of my raster as shown:

#reading in my raster

```
abvco2=raster("Avitabile_AGB_Map.tif")
```

#clipping it to Indonesia

```
abvco2new=mask(abvco2,Indonesia)
```

#finding the area

```
area=area(abvco2new)
```

However, area() is not helpful as it does not return me with a single area value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `area` function is to compute cell sizes for lon/lat data. From what you say that does not apply to your case. All cells have the same size, so the area of the raster `x` is

```
ncell(x) * prod(dim(x)[1:2])
```

Here is a minimal reproducible example

```
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
x <- raster(f)

# area of one cell 
aone <- prod(dim(x)[1:2])
# total area
ncell(x) * aone
# 84640000
```

If you want to exclude some areas (e.g. `NA`) you can use `cellStats` or `zonal`
Area excluding NA

```
b <- cellStats(!is.na(x), sum)
b * aone
#[1] 29237600
```